# How can i upload image using nodejs only

Tags: node.js, image

I am not using Express and any other npm package to perform this task
anybody can help in this task

I tried to use base64 enoding and stuff but i am not able to understand when i taking buffer and write it to my linux system it is giving me a image that is not type of png while opening it with image viewer.

Comment: Read a file buffer from request, and write it to the Linux server using fs module

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload an image file in Node.js without using any npm packages, you can use the built-in http and fs modules. Here's an example of how you can do it:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  if (req.method === 'POST' && req.url === '/upload') {
    const chunks = [];

    req.on('data', (chunk) => {
      chunks.push(chunk);
    });

    req.on('end', () => {
      const buffer = Buffer.concat(chunks);
      const filename = 'image.png';

      fs.writeFile(filename, buffer, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          res.statusCode = 500;
          res.end('Error uploading file');
        } else {
          res.statusCode = 200;
          res.end('File uploaded successfully');
        }
      });
    });
  } else {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.end(`
      <html>
        <body>
          <form method="POST" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="image" />
            <button type="submit">Upload</button>
          </form>
        </body>
      </html>
    `);
  }
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server running at http://localhost:3000');
});
```